# Access VBA to update Access table from SQL Server table source

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have created the code below to test whether I can run a query and retrieve a data from an SQL server table. And so far I can return the result using a `MessageBox`, but somehow I just don't know how to use this connection to update the table inside this Access file. Basically I want to use this as a front end file. Then, when the form is open it will automatically update the table inside this access file and load the data to the combo box as a list. I tried searching it here and read many discussions here and in Google but currently I can't find the right solution.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub LocalServerConn_Test()


Set conn = New adodb.Connection
Set rst = New adodb.Recordset


strDBName = "DataSet"

strConnectString = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security = SSPI; " & _
    "Initial Catalog = " & strDBName & "; Persist Security Info = True; " & _
        "Worksation ID = abc123;"

            conn.ConnectionString = strConnectString

                conn.Open


strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT dbo.abc.abc123 FROM dbo.abc"


rst.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=strConnectString, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No records returned"

    Else

        rst.MoveFirst
            Do While Not rst.EOF
                MsgBox rst.Fields("abc123").Value
                    rst.MoveNext
            Loop

End If

conn.Close
rst.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use code very similar to this:

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
cdb.Execute _
        "DELETE FROM LocalTable", _
        dbFailOnError
cdb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO LocalTable (abc123) " & _
        "SELECT DISTINCT abc123 " & _
        "FROM " & _
            "[" & _
                "ODBC;" & _
                "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
                "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                "Database=DataSet;" & _
                "Trusted_Connection=yes;" & _
            "].[dbo.abc]", _
        dbFailOnError
Set cdb = Nothing
```

You can just keep the combo box bound to [LocalTable] and the updated values from the SQL Server table should appear.

Comment: I'm sorry I might be very general in my question so I hope you could help me with this specifically. basically I would like to update a table in the Access file from an SQL Server. But I need to run a query first from SQL Server.

Lets say I have a huge data table in SQL Server. I need to run a query "SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM SQLServerName" from access vba, then also a table from the same Access file will be updated by using the result of the query from the SQL Server.